# How to handle requests if no matching spring security <intercept-url>?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using spring 3.1.1 and spring security 3.1.0.  I'd like to enforce a policy that all http requests that are not explicitly configured with an `<intercept-url pattern="..." access="..."/>` entry are handled in a particular way.  For requests that match a configured `<intercept-url/>` I want to use typical role based access decisions.  However, for non-matching requests, I want to either respond with a 404 (not found) (or maybe 403/forbidden). I want to do this so that I and other team members are forced to explicitly configure spring security and associated roles for any new endpoints.

I originally thought that I could use `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll"/>` as the last `intercept-url` and that spring would do what I wanted.  This technique works if the user is already authenticated but is a little strange for unauthenticated/anonymous users. For anonymous users, spring detects (in `ExceptionTranslationFilter`) that the user is anonymous and starts the authentication process when requests like `/missingResource` are processed. Typically this means that the user is redirected to a login form and, after logging in, is redirected back to `/missingResource`.  So the user has to login in order to see a 404 (not found) page.

I ended up removing the `intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll"/>` and writing a custom filter that runs `after="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"` and responds with 404 for requests that are not matched by the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` but it seemed a little complicated.  Is there a better or simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

you can define a separate http element for intercept url /** with access ="denyAll" and add a custom entry-point-ref to avoid spring to redirect user to login form, you can use existing entryPoint Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint for showing 403 error response or implement your own by implementing AuthenticationEntryPoint.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My main http section already has a `pattern="/**"` that contains all of the `intercept-url` entries. You cannot define two `pattern="/**"` http sections.